# Ordinary Differential equation-integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the differential equation

$(3y^2-x)+2y(y^2-3)y'=0$

admits an integrating factor which is a function of $(x+y^2)$.

Hence solve the equation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please share your own thoughts about the problem. Where do you get stuck? What don't you understand? ... Also, please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your questions, since it will be easier for others to read. Again, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**A sketch:**

Assume $I=e^{\int f(x+y^2)d(x+y^2)}$ is an integrating factor of the ODE. (If you understand how the idea of integrating factor work, this is nature to write it in this form, instead of simply $f(x+y^2)$. And I think this is the only tricky thing we need to solve it.)

By definition of integrating factor,
$$I \cdot (3y^2-x)dx+I \cdot 2y(y^2-3)dy=0$$ will be exact, i.e. $$\frac{\partial (I \cdot (3y^2-x))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (I \cdot 2y(y^2-3))}{\partial x}.$$

Hence we just need to find one possible $f(x+y^2)$. It is straightforward: we only need to evaluate $LHS$ and $RHS$, comparing them, then we will get the requiring $f$, and hence $I$.

Now you can treat the ODE with usual way. If you're still confusing, please let me know.